# Understanding performance characteristics of Wadler's Prettier Printer

Tags: pretty-print, idris

I am using the Prettier Printer implementation from the `contrib` library in `Idris`.

When I fold with the `|//|` operator on a list of `Doc`s, the performance quickly explodes, i.e. the following code doesn't terminate before I lose my patience:

```
*IdrisFMT\PrettyDocs> :exec toString 0 15 $ fold (|//|) $ map text $ words "this is a long sentence with a lot of words that I can use for testing the performance of the prettier printer implementation. I need a few more words to prove my point, though."
```

Please note, the above fold is equal to the pre-defined combinator `fillCat`.

If I instead use the pre-defined `cat` combinator (`= group . vcat`), it terminates within a second:

```
*IdrisFMT\PrettyDocs> :exec toString 0 15 $ cat $ map text $ words "this is a long sentence with a lot of words that I can use for testing the performance of the prettier printer implementation. I need a few more words to prove my point, though."
"this\nis\na\nlong\nsentence\nwith\na\nlot\nof\nwords\nthat\nI\ncan\nuse\nfor\ntesting\nthe\nperformance\nof\nthe\nprettier\nprinter\nimplementation.\nI\nneed\na\nfew\nmore\nwords\nto\nprove\nmy\npoint,\nthough."
```

The `Doc` adt version of `cat $ map text $ words "this is a long sentence with a lot of words that I can use for testing the performance of the prettier printer implementation. I need a few more words to prove my point, though."` can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/4AJWcGnD

I understand that the `cat` combinator solves a much simpler problem, but I fail to see how `fillCat` is so complex as to never terminate.

Could this be caused by a mistake in the implementation, or am I simply constructing too complex a document?

**EDIT**

The definition of the `|//|` operator is found here:
https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/contrib/Text/PrettyPrint/WL/Combinators.idr#L65-L69

```
||| The document `(x |//| y)` concatenates document `x` and `y` with
||| a 'softbreak' in between. This effectively puts `x` and `y` either
||| right next to each other or underneath each other.
(|//|) : Doc -> Doc -> Doc
(|//|) = concatDoc softBreak
```

Comment: I have no idea, but I wonder if that could be related to the quadratic blow-up that `++` has on lists when folded. IIRC `foldl' (++) [] listOfStrings` has a bad performance. Perhaps `fold (|//|)` has a similar issue?

Comment: Please note that this is `Idris`, so I'm not even sure the same holds true here (afaik, strings are not lists in `Idris`).

Comment: could you include the definition of `|//|`. Also does the same problem happen if you compile instead of execute inside the interpreter?

Comment: Are you getting the same behaviour with `fillCat` used directly?

Comment: fillCat is literally defined as fold (|//|) but yes I tried both. I'll add the operator definition when I'm back on my machine

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I have just tried compiling to a binary with the same result. Also, I'm pretty convinced that :exec does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer but it could give some hints to someone with a better understanding of `prettyprint` library. I used the [Idris JVM bytecode backend](https://github.com/mmhelloworld/idris-jvm) to diagnose this as I am working on the backend and I was curious to see how it behaves on the JVM. Unsurprisingly the behavior was the same: the first snippet just hangs and the second one works but to debug, I was able to use the JVM tool, **jvisualvm**, to take the thread dump and profile CPU.

**Here is the thread dump:**

```
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.lambda$$lbraceText$dotPrettyPrint$dotWL$dotCore$dotrender$colonbest$colon0_lam_0$rbrace$26(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main$$Lambda$18/189568618.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.lambda$render$1(Unknown Source)
        at Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core$$Lambda$16/1531448569.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.mmhelloworld.idrisjvm.runtime.Runtime.unwrap(Runtime.java:37)
        at main.Main.main(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.$lbracerunMain_0$rbrace(Unknown Source)
        at main.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

**CPU profiling result from jvisualvm:**
[image]

As we can see from the thread dump, this method call `Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core.render$colonbest$colon0` keeps repeating in the
 stack trace and, from the CPU profiling, that function is the top hot spot. This method corresponds to `best` function defined within `render` function of `Text.PrettyPrint.WL.Core` module available [here](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/contrib/Text/PrettyPrint/WL/Core.idr#L171). I am not much familiar with this code but it looks like the [`best` function](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/contrib/Text/PrettyPrint/WL/Core.idr#L171) keeps calling itself without terminating the recursion.

Comment: While this is interesting, I think I had already come to the same conclusion. It doesn't fit the performance characteristic described in Wadler's paper that's linear in the size of the document (the "document" can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/4AJWcGnD) 

At this point, I'm guessing there is some part of this implementation that doesn't follow the optimizations described in the paper.